# Exception on publishing PowerBI report

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

When publishing a PowerBI report, sometimes it fails out and you'll get a weird exception:

> microsoft.powerbi.client.windows.services.powerbiwebexception

I spent far too long trying to find the answer, no records exist on how to fix this as of writing this post. Answer provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observations, there seems to be a limit near 200~ reports per account. Note this is not data size ( storage ) we're talking about, but the volume ( count ) of reports.

I don't know if additional app-workspaces affect the total number that causes the exception.

The solution is to delete some reports in your PBI service environment.